# Is the Gray code unique?

Tags: digital-logic, code

After googling, I found that a Gray code is not unique and the only requirement for a sequence of binary strings to be a Gray code is that two adjacent binary strings differ by only one bit. Can we consider `010` → `110` → `100` → `000` to be a Gray code sequence?

If so, it seems that many sequences comply with the requirement to be a Gray code, so when we apply a Gray code in real life, such as for error correction, can we use our *own* Gray code (such as defining a sequence of my choosing that meets the requirement of being a Gray code)?

Comment: @Antonio51 that is a possible, yet very wide definition of a Gray code. It for example also allows to call a code for 16 different values "Gray code" if you used 15 bit values to represent these 16 different values, and just do the sequence 1. `000…000`, 2. `100…000`, 3. `110…000`, 4. `1110…000`, …, 14.`111…110`, 15. `111…111`. Is allowing arbitrary many bits for representing values a useful definition? IMHO, not. Gray's patent **expicitly** refers to binary-reflected codes, and the definition you found looks like what a lazy student wrote down as a note, not an actual definition.

Comment: @Antonio51: geeksforgeeks is one of the least authoritative sites you could cite.  Most of the stuff I've found there is tutorials written by beginners as they try to understand a new subject, so misunderstandings and misconceptions are not rare.  Without any voting mechanism, and comments not displayed prominently, many problems go unfixed with future readers none the wiser.

Comment: Note that you used 3 bits to encode 4 states.

Comment: @LamarLatrell: In many situations, the number of states that could be encoded with the available bits will exceed the number of states that need to be handled, and codes other than a binary reflected code may be advantageous.  In a binary reflected code, the state of one of the bits will be depedent upon the state of all of the remaining bits.  In something like a Johnson counter, by contrast, each bit's state is dependent upon only one other bit (or maybe two bits outside itself if one needs the counter to recover from arbitrary invalid states).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your example is a code that only changes in a single position between successive elements. But: It's not a well-chosen code, especially not one found as *binary reflected code*, the method described in said patent to construct such codes, because it uses 3 bits to encode only four states. That's superfluous, 01, 11, 10, 00 would have done the same, and having more bits doesn't help.

I'll go and say that if you want to Gray-encode a sequence of \$2^n\$ values, a Gray code must consist of words  of exactly \$n\$ bits length, otherwise the encoding is wasteful.

Then, Gray refers to *binary-reflected codes* in [his patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2632058).

Let us look at these: by design, binary-reflected codes not only have a Hamming distance between successive values, but also between the first and the last element – by design. I'd require that property from *any* code you're calling Gray Code. [Transistor's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/690116/64158)'s rotational encoding disk graciously illustrates why: only these can encode things that happen in cycles (angles, phases) with the desired 1-bit difference between successive values.

Therefore, any *cyclic shift* of a binary-reflected code still has the Hamming distance property you want – neighbors differing only in a single bit.

I'm willing to call these shifts of binary-reflected codes "Gray Codes" as well. So, if you construct one \$2^n\$-length Gray code, you automatically get \$n\$ Gray codes, as there's inherently \$n\$ positions by which you can shift the code.

So, yes, there's a lot of them – since we can always a construct a binary-reflected code for any word length \$n\in\mathbb N\$, and due to the shifting, there's at least \$n\$ different Gray Codes.

There's actually more! You can choose a Gray Code according to your needs. Due to shift invariance as described above, you can freely choose any sequence element from a Gray Code you find as a starting point – handy if you don't want to start with the all-0 code word, for example. But, there's also opportunities to change properties.

Binary-reflected codes have bad properties if you want, for example, send them through a parallel data connection, where the first physical line transports the first bit, the second line the second bit, and so on. Look at the disk in Transistor's answer: the outermost bit toggles every two code elements, the next-inner every four, and so on. Therefore, the physical line to transport the outermost bit would need to have \$2^n\$ the bandwidth than the innermost one! Terrible! Different kinds of cables for different bits, with different delays? That is very annoying to implement. So, *balanced Gray Codes* change bits by a different order. There's also at least one set of \$n\$ such codes that you can find (again, due to finding one meaning finding \$n\$ that are just cyclic shifts) for \$n\$-length words for \$n=2^m,\quad m\in\mathbb N\$, and because by definition binary-reflected codes (and their shiftings) are *not* possibly balanced and hence a disjoint set, we've now already found at least \$2n\$ different Gray Codes for power-of-two word lengths.

So, yes, you get to choose your Gray code.

Comment: Some one-change-at-a-time encodings may not assign values to all combinations of bit values, but be advantageous for other reasons.  For example, there's a rotary encoder that has an 8-bit output, and has the property that rotating a wheel right 1/8 turn will cause the code to be rotated one bit to the right, which allows the encoder to be simpler than a binary reflected code encoder.

Comment: I was reading something recently- which of course I can't find any more- about a 2D encoding based on Gray codes used for e.g. geolocation. Apparently, even for relatively small e.g. 6x6 codes, the computation required to find the best layout was significant.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd communications engineering uses Gray Codes for assignment of bit strings to *constellation points* of *QAM* constellations, which really just means that you take a square grid of points on the plane, and assign values from 000.. to 111.. to them, so that mistaking a point for one of its four neighbors (above, below, left, right) only leads to a single bit error. For even-power-of-two square grids, that's super easy. It becomes hard with more dimensions or mappings of spheres.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm an engineer. I know. I still can't find the stuff I was reading, but from my POV it was interesting that- at least according to the authors- once tags got big it took a substantial mount of time to precompute the "best" set with guaranteed Hamming distance.

Comment: In fact, any _bit permutation_ of the "standard" binary-reflected Gray code is still a Gray code, so there are at least \$n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (n-1) \cdot n\$ equivalent \$n\$ bit Gray codes. You can also invert any bit(s) of the code, giving a total of \$2^n \cdot n!\$ equivalent codes. And that still doesn't include e.g. the balanced Gray codes (which also have at least \$2^n \cdot n!\$ equivalents each).

Comment: Hey @MarkMorganLloyd there was no intention to pretend you're not well-informed :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller :-) although I'd feel better informed if I could locate the stuff I was reading... it's rare to find somebody admitting to needing (at least) hours of brute-force processing now that "the cloud" and "AI" provide universal panaceas. There is, of course, always a possibility that their algorithms were excessively brute-force and could have benefited from some sort of constraint-guided approach. I think Ilmari Karonen's point about there being factorials involved is telling...

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd yeah, I was very tempted to write a short program to just list all Gray codes for a given block length, but out of the \$2^n!\$ possible non-repeating sequences of \$n\$ length words, it's still dauntingly many that you'd have to try in a naive way ("start with an arbitrary word, flip one bit, giving you the next word, flip any other bit than in the last step, check whether you've already had that word…, flip any bit (aside from the one that you flipped last step)…"); \$n\cdot (n-1)^{n-1}\$ is still a metric fudgeton of a lot.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Elsewhere, I once asked a question about the knight's tour problem and was rewarded by a couple of solutions within minutes. It turned out that the elderly gentleman who provided them had access to top-of-the-line constraint-solving software, and used it to supplement his pension by designing Sodoku puzzles of carefully-tailored difficulty.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd that doesn't sound like a bad thing :) I remember planning to throw Z3 at channel code design problems, then um, stopped, after doing a back-of-envelope estimate of complexity. Definitely something I plan to revisit for smaller problems.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Found it: Apriltags. "...I did run the tagStandard41h12 to completion, but I doubt that I would have spent more than a week..." https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag-generation/issues/9 That would have generated something like 2,117 distinct tags (i.e. resistant to rotation etc.); that's a pretty big and sparse search space, but it looks fertile for optimisation research.

Answer (score 11):

Tip: "Gray Code" is a proper noun so it gets capitalised.

> I found that Gray Code is not unique ...

Your meaning is unclear here. If you mean that it can repeat within itself than that is correct. The most common example would be a 2-bit rotary encoder which would have a sequence `00-01-11-10`.

> ... and the only requirement for a sequence of binary numbers to be gray code is that two adjacent binary numbers differ by only one bit.

That is generally corrct.

> So, can we consider 010->110->100->000 to be a sequence of gray code?

It looks OK to me but we can see that the third bit is redundant as it never changes.

> If so, it seems that many sequences of code comply with the requirement to be Gray Code, then when we apply Gray Code in real life, such as error correction, we can use our own Gray Code (such as defining a sequence of code I like that meets the requirement of being Gray Code)?

I suspect that this is not quite true. As far as I can see (see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) article, for example) a true Gray Code as envisaged by Gray is a "reflected binary code". This is most easily seen in the patterns of absolute rotary encoders which use a true Gray Code.

[image]

*Figure 1. Encoder pattern. Source: [Rozum](https://rozum.com/absolute-position-encoders/).*

There's a good little paper on [Encoder.com](https://www.encoder.com/hubfs/white-papers/WP-2010_Gray-Codes/wp2010-gray-codes-natural-binary-codes-and-conversions.pdf?hsLang=en#:%7E:text=Gray%20Code%20is%20a%20form%20of%20binary%20that%20uses%20a,the%20data%20must%20be%20incorrect) which explains some techniques that I wasn't aware of regarding conversion of Gray to binary. You might be interested.

Comment: Tip: "Gray" is capitalised since even minimum research will show that it was somebody's name. "Code" doesn't have to be, since as OP points out it's not unique.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: By interesting linguistic coincidence, the first time I encountered the term Gray code was in an article about a grayscale video digitizer.

Comment: I think I can see where it could overlap with dithering etc. In my case it was in the context of Karnaugh charts (contrary to what some believe, 7400-series TTL did exist when I was a student).

Comment: "corrct" is incorrect, was it intentional? :)

Answer (score 6):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Invention):

> In principle, there can be more than one such code for a given word
> length, but the term Gray code was first applied to a particular
> binary code for non-negative integers, the binary-reflected Gray code,
> or BRGC.

However, in practice I have seen the term "Gray code" applied very loosely to any sequence where a single bit is changed.

Answer (score 5):

If you were to use scholar.google for a search on Gray codes, you will find that there is quite a bit of mathematical literature on the existence of (generalized) Gray codes. In Combinatorics, a Gray code is any complete enumeration of binary numbers of a given length (padded with zeroes at the beginning if necessary) so that any two consecutive elements of the enumeration change in only one bit. In addition, the beginning and the end element of the enumeration also have to differ by at most one digit. Your example is not a Gray code because it is not a complete enumeration, you would need to have 2**3 = 8 elements.

Knuth's Art of Computer Programming Volume 4 has a lot of information on Gray codes and their uses.

As other answers already pointed out, the original Gray code was a specific code. The term Gray code for the generalizations is however already well-established.